# Decimal to binary - wrong result

Tags: javascript, binary, numbers, decimal

Have a question! Why this code :

```
let number = 6063311135418901680;
let binary = parseInt(number, 10).toString(2);
console.log(binary);
```

returns `101010000100101001101010101101001010101010100000110010000000000` and not `0101010000100101001101010101101001010101010100000110010010110000` (which is suppose to be the right answer)? I try to convert decimal to binary but maybe i didn t get the right way.I know there is alot of infomation about numbers, but didn`t find nothing to help me.

Comment: `if( number > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) throw new Error("Numbers don't work that way, you guys!");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0101010000100101001101010101101001010101010100000110010010110000
```

can't be represented in a variable of type "number" in Javascript for two reasons:

- numbers don't hold leading zeros
- integers greater than [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) can't usually be exactly represented

The reason behind those constraints is that numbers are stored as [IEEE754 double precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If you need greater integers, either keep them as string or use a big numbers library.